# LPC824 microcontroller ADC demo HardFault problem

Tags: embedded, clang, adc, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to program **LPC824** microcontroller board ([https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/2265/][1]) with **LPCOpen**. 
I'm using it with LPCLink 2 debugger board.

My goal is to get some information from the "pressure sensor" with an ADC.

My code stops with a **HardFault** when executing a **`NVIC_EnableIRQ`** function(on line: 92).

If I don't use "NVIC interrupt controller" then my code works and I can get value from sensor with ADC.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is my adc.c code:

```
#include "board.h"

static volatile int ticks;
static bool sequenceComplete = false;
static bool thresholdCrossed = false;

#define TICKRATE_HZ (100)     /* 100 ticks per second */

#define BOARD_ADC_CH 2

/**
 * @brief     Handle interrupt from ADC sequencer A
 * @return     Nothing
 */
void ADC_SEQA_IRQHandler(void) {
    uint32_t pending;

    /* Get pending interrupts */
    pending = Chip_ADC_GetFlags(LPC_ADC);

    /* Sequence A completion interrupt */
    if (pending & ADC_FLAGS_SEQA_INT_MASK) {
        sequenceComplete = true;
    }

    /* Threshold crossing interrupt on ADC input channel */
    if (pending & ADC_FLAGS_THCMP_MASK(BOARD_ADC_CH)) {
        thresholdCrossed = true;
    }

    /* Clear any pending interrupts */
    Chip_ADC_ClearFlags(LPC_ADC, pending);
}

/**
 * @brief     Handle interrupt from SysTick timer
 * @return     Nothing
 */
void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    static uint32_t count;

    /* Every 1/2 second */
    if (count++ == TICKRATE_HZ / 2) {
        count = 0;
        Chip_ADC_StartSequencer(LPC_ADC, ADC_SEQA_IDX);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief     main routine for ADC example
 * @return     Function should not exit
 */
int main(void) {
    uint32_t rawSample;
    int j;

    SystemCoreClockUpdate();
    Board_Init();

    /* Setup ADC for 12-bit mode and normal power */
    Chip_ADC_Init(LPC_ADC, 0);
    Chip_ADC_Init(LPC_ADC, ADC_CR_MODE10BIT);

    /* Need to do a calibration after initialization and trim */
    Chip_ADC_StartCalibration(LPC_ADC);
    while (!(Chip_ADC_IsCalibrationDone(LPC_ADC))) {
    }

    /* Setup for maximum ADC clock rate using sycnchronous clocking */
    Chip_ADC_SetClockRate(LPC_ADC, ADC_MAX_SAMPLE_RATE);

    Chip_ADC_SetupSequencer(LPC_ADC, ADC_SEQA_IDX,
            (ADC_SEQ_CTRL_CHANSEL(BOARD_ADC_CH) | ADC_SEQ_CTRL_MODE_EOS));
    Chip_Clock_EnablePeriphClock(SYSCTL_CLOCK_SWM);
    Chip_SWM_EnableFixedPin(SWM_FIXED_ADC2);
    Chip_Clock_DisablePeriphClock(SYSCTL_CLOCK_SWM);

    /* Setup threshold 0 low and high values to about 25% and 75% of max */
    Chip_ADC_SetThrLowValue(LPC_ADC, 0, ((1 * 0xFFF) / 4));
    Chip_ADC_SetThrHighValue(LPC_ADC, 0, ((3 * 0xFFF) / 4));

    Chip_ADC_ClearFlags(LPC_ADC, Chip_ADC_GetFlags(LPC_ADC));
    Chip_ADC_EnableInt(LPC_ADC,
            (ADC_INTEN_SEQA_ENABLE | ADC_INTEN_OVRRUN_ENABLE));
    Chip_ADC_SelectTH0Channels(LPC_ADC, ADC_THRSEL_CHAN_SEL_THR1(BOARD_ADC_CH));
    Chip_ADC_SetThresholdInt(LPC_ADC, BOARD_ADC_CH, ADC_INTEN_THCMP_CROSSING);

    /* Enable ADC NVIC interrupt */
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_SEQA_IRQn);

    Chip_ADC_EnableSequencer(LPC_ADC, ADC_SEQA_IDX);

    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / TICKRATE_HZ);

    /* Endless loop */
    while (1) {
        /* Sleep until something happens */
        __WFI();

        if (thresholdCrossed) {
            thresholdCrossed = false;
            printf("********ADC threshold event********\r\n");
        }

        /* Is a conversion sequence complete? */
        if (sequenceComplete) {
            sequenceComplete = false;

            /* Get raw sample data for channels 0-11 */
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                rawSample = Chip_ADC_GetDataReg(LPC_ADC, j);
                /* Show some ADC data */
                if (rawSample & (ADC_DR_OVERRUN | ADC_SEQ_GDAT_DATAVALID)) {
                    printf("Chan: %d Val: %d\r\n", j, ADC_DR_RESULT(rawSample));
                    printf("Threshold range: 0x%x ",
                            ADC_DR_THCMPRANGE(rawSample));
                    printf("Threshold cross: 0x%x\r\n",
                            ADC_DR_THCMPCROSS(rawSample));
                    printf("Overrun: %s ",
                            (rawSample & ADC_DR_OVERRUN) ? "true" : "false");
                    printf("Data Valid: %s\r\n\r\n",
                            (rawSample & ADC_SEQ_GDAT_DATAVALID) ?
                                    "true" : "false");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the interrupt vectors set up to call `ADC_SEQA_IRQHandler`? Any details about that HardFault, register values?

Answer (score 1):

Hard fault usually means that you try to execute code outside allowed addresses. If you have not registered the interrupt in the vector table but enabled it, the MCU will jump to whatever address that's written there instead, after which the program crashes.

How to fix that depends on tool chain. Assuming LPCXpresso, you have several options to set up libraries (I don't know about LPCOpen specifically), so where to find the vector table is different from case to case. However, this works quite similar on most MCUs, ARM or not. Somewhere in a "crt start-up" file you should have something along the lines of this:

```
void (* const g_pfnVectors[])(void) = ...
```

This is an array of function pointers which will be the vector table allocated in memory at address 0 on Cortex M. You have to place your function at the relevant interrupt vector. For example it may say something like

```
PIN_INT0_IRQHandler,                     // PIO INT0
```

If that's the interrupt you should implement, then you replace that line:

```
#include "my_irq_stuff.h"
...

void (* const g_pfnVectors[])(void) = 
...
my_INT0,                                 // PIO INT0
```

Assuming `my_irq_stuff.h` contains the function prototype `my_INT0` for the interrupt service routine. The actual routine should be implemented in the corresponding .c file.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm too newbie and my knowledge is not enough just now. Now I'm studying basic knowledge like this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/embedded_systems/es_interrupts.htm Thank you for guided :).